# Should I use the same parent name class for a derived class if they are in different namespaces?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am in the following situation:

- I have an abstract class named Configuration.

  - The class models an application configuration properties and methods.
  - This class is located in its own namespace.
- Each application has its own configuration class inherited from Configuration.
- Each application has its own namespace.
- Each application has only one instance of the configuration class (singleton).

The question is if I should name every derived class differently (i.e. AppAConfiguration, AppBConfiguration) or, giving each application has its own namespace, use Configuration as the name for the derived classes.

I think it is doable and it is semantically coherent but also it seems a bit weird to have classes with the same name.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for confusion to me. Anyone seeing `Configuration` in a source file using it will need to look at the using directives to see which is meant.... it sounds like `Configuration` should be `ConfigurationBase`, then you can have `AppAConfiguration`, even if it's already in an `AppA` namespace.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I like your suggestion. It may seem simple but the more I think about it the more confusing I find it :) I really needed an outsider point of view. Could a good practice be to name abstract classes with the Base suffix?

Comment: "Could a good practice be to name abstract classes with the Base suffix?" - Yes, that's a common .NET convention. (Although there are counterarguments too - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2005/12/16/i-dont-like-the-base-suffix/)

Comment: I'm somebody who works with your code. I look at your code. I see a class Configuration and another class Configuration. Now, I am in the field, so I should have no problems to guess what a class does from it's name, however, there are two classes of the same name. Huh. In short: Why would you do this? What would be the advantage over AppAConfiguration and AppBConfiguration? If it has none, then why do it?